# SQL Change Counter - Checking for First and Final Value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've been trying to check the total count of times a user id that started (before) at a number 4,5, or 6 changed **and ended** (After). So in this case, we would add +1 to the 4 to 4 counter for ID 62360 as well as +1 to the 4 to 5 counter for ID 61874.

Data Table:

```
ID  Before  After   Date
61874   4   6   2021-06-04 14:53:25
61874   6   5   2021-06-04 14:55:30
62360   4   6   2021-06-03 14:18:31
62360   6   4   2021-06-03 14:18:33
62360   4   6   2021-06-03 14:18:37
62360   6   4   2021-06-03 14:18:39
```

Desired Output:

```
Changes Tot.Count 
4 to 4  1
4 to 5  1
4 to 6  0
5 to 4  0
5 to 5  0
5 to 6  0
6 to 4  0
6 to 5  0
6 to 6  0
```

I had trouble getting the output above that tabulates the changes as as documented in the changes / count table.

I am only interested in the counting the first **Before** case and last **after** case for each ID but had difficulty drafting this. I believe it has to be a cobination of a grouping, CTE and lag function.

```
select CASE
           WHEN () THEN '4 to 4'
           WHEN () THEN '4 to 5'
           WHEN () THEN '4 to 6'
           WHEN () THEN '5 to 4'
           WHEN () THEN '5 to 5'
           WHEN () THEN '5 to 6'
           WHEN () THEN '6 to 4'
           WHEN () THEN '6 to 5'
           WHEN () THEN '6 to 6'
        end as changes,
       count(*) as Count_Changes 
from data group by 2;
```

If it is possible, a python script may be able to do so but not sure how to implement the case statement as a python function

Comment: It is not clear whether your first example is a given data table or a desired result, please clarify.  If a data table then just Select concat(to_char(before,'999'),' to ', to-char(after,'999')) as Change, count(*) as Count From whatever Group By concat(to_char(before,'999'),' to ', to-char(after,'999')).

Comment: Thanks for the Feedback @ChrisMaurer. Indeed the first example is the given data table from which I am attempting to get a count/grouping per the CTE above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want first value of `before` column and last value of `after` column for each `ID`. Here `first_value` and `last_value` will help you.

first we will get the value for each group using below query:

```
select 
distinct on (id)
id,
first_value(before) over (partition by id order by date_) "fv",
last_value(after) over (partition by id order by date_  RANGE BETWEEN 
            UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 
            UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) "lv" 
from data ) tab
```

Above query will give you output like below:

```
61874   4   5
62360   4   4
```

To get the exact output use below query:

```
with cte as (
select *, 
case when fv=4 and lv=4 then '4 to 4' 
 when fv=4 and lv=5 then '4 to 5'
 when fv=4 and lv=6 then '4 to 6'
 when fv=5 and lv=4 then '5 to 4'
 when fv=5 and lv=5 then '5 to 5'
 when fv=5 and lv=6 then '5 to 6'
 when fv=6 and lv=4 then '6 to 4'
 when fv=6 and lv=5 then '6 to 5'
 when fv=6 and lv=6 then '6 to 6'
end "range" from (
select 
distinct on (id)
id,
first_value(before) over (partition by id order by date_) "fv",
last_value(after) over (partition by id order by date_  RANGE BETWEEN 
            UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 
            UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) "lv" 
from data ) tab

)

select tab.col1 "Changes", count("range") "Tot.Count" from (
values('4 to 4'),('4 to 5'),('4 to 6'),('5 to 4'),('5 to 5'),('5 to 6'),('6 to 4'),('6 to 5'),('6 to 6')
) tab(col1) 
left join cte on tab.col1=cte."range"

group by 1 order by 1
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=d47f285c0771b672d9cf91c3e65e74a8)

Answer (score 1):

I think I would handle this a bit differently.  There is no need to actually get the first "before" and last "after" value in a single row.  There is also no need to list all possible combinations of the before an after values, because they can be generated.

You can generate the combinations of values in the final query.  You can get the first "before" and last "after" in separate queries and just join them in:

```
with ba (val) as (
      values (4), (5), (6)
     )
select ba_before.val as from_val, ba_after.val as after_val, count(a.id),
       ba_before.val || ' to ' || ba_after.val as string_version
from ba ba_before cross join
     ba ba_after left join
     (select distinct on (id) id, before
      from data
      order by id, date asc
     ) b
     on b.before = ba_before.val left join
     (select distinct on (id) id, after
      from data
      order by id, date desc
     ) a
     on a.id = b.id and
        a.after = ba_after.val
group by 1, 2;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5a6bbba3985dd84d0da7d0163aa3c81d) is a db<>fiddle.

You can generate the `ba` list -- if you prefer -- directly form the data:

```
with ba as (
      select distinct val
      from data cross join lateral
           (values (before), (after)) v(val)
     )
```

Note that this can also make use of indexes on `(id, date asc)`/`(id, date desc)` for the  subqueries.  That can be a big performance boost if you are working with a large amount of data.